# PE file add null bytes to .text section

Tags: assembly, patch, portable-executable

I have an exe that I need to increase the size of its .text section . 
used LORDPE to alter the Virtual and Raw address, but having a hard time where to append the null bytes ? Do I need to reallocate every following section ?

Is there a tool for similar tasks ? 
following these links

[tut2](http://www.hellboundhackers.org/articles/842-Evading-Anti-Virus-Detection.html)

[tut1](http://www.woodmann.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-14938.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you must do depends on how many bytes you want to add to the section and the status of the section. If you just add a few bytes and the section has a gap big enough to contain the bytes to add, then you must only change the size of the section, NOT its address. If there is no gap in the section or the gap is not large enough to host the new bytes, then you must add a new section.

Comment: let me make sure I understand you here's my case :

.text VOffset 1000 , VSize 6FAA

.rdata VOffset 8000 

does that gives me 8000 - 7faa = 56 bytes gap ?

Comment: I increased the VSize and RawSize of .text section 55 bytes and the exe worked :)

Comment: happy it works now. :-) Should my answer be correct, I would appreciate that you mark it as such.