# PE File .text Section Size

Tags: c, portable-executable

I wrote code and compiled it to exe, now the .text section need to be larger , 
If I have the code and I want to allocate more space in the .text section from code before compiling it  , how to do so ? Allocate some buffers ?

I'm trying to alter the code or compiling option to result with a binary file with LARGER .TEXT section

my compiler VisualStudio2010 or cl.exe

Patching the binary file is more complicated

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I edited question above

Comment: Compiling options depend on the compiler you're using. Which one is it?

Comment: Why does it matter? I usually try to get my executable file as small as possible. What are you binary patching, from where? Why not put the code in the executable in the first place?

Comment: It matters because 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109305/pe-file-add-null-bytes-to-text-section  https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/1251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's really what you want, you may use inline assembly. E.g. for gcc+gas: `void unused_global() { __asm(".space 10000"); }`

For Visual Studio's cl.exe, it seems to be more tricky: there is no directives in inline asm, even REPT is unavailable. I would compile a bunch of nops separately with masm; otherwise we have to do something like this:

```
#define NOP __asm { NOP } ;
#define NOP8 NOP NOP NOP NOP NOP NOP NOP NOP
#define NOP64 NOP8 NOP8 NOP8 NOP8 NOP8 NOP8 NOP8 NOP8 
#define NOP512 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64
#define NOP4096 NOP512 NOP512 NOP512 NOP512 NOP512 NOP512 NOP512 NOP512
#define NOP32768 NOP4096 NOP4096 NOP4096 NOP4096 NOP4096 NOP4096 NOP4096 NOP4096
void unused_global() { NOP32768 }
```

Comment: I just added that i'm using cl.exe , Visual Studio 2012 
sorry for not specifying that before