# Extra space at the beginning/end of .text section

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-injection, portable-executable, sections

I'm looking for a way to reserve some extra space at the begining/end of the .text section from C/C++ using Visual Studio compiler.

I've only found one solution on how to reserve some extra space in code section in Visual Studio:
[PE File .text Section Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170748/pe-file-text-section-size?rq=1)

```
#pragma optimize( "", off )
#define NOP __asm { NOP } ;
#define NOP8 NOP NOP NOP NOP NOP NOP NOP NOP
#define NOP64 NOP8 NOP8 NOP8 NOP8 NOP8 NOP8 NOP8 NOP8 
#define NOP512 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64
#define NOP4096 NOP512 NOP512 NOP512 NOP512 NOP512 NOP512 NOP512 NOP512
#define NOP32768 NOP4096 NOP4096 NOP4096 NOP4096 NOP4096 NOP4096 NOP4096 NOP4096
void unused_global() { NOP32768 }
#pragma optimize( "", on )

int main() {
   [...]
   unused_global(); // <-- Without this call, compiler doesn't include `unused_global` inside .text section
}
```

The problems with this solution are:

1. It requires a direct call to this function. This of course will
   break the application logic.
2. It doesn't guarantee that
   `unused_global` function will be placed at the end/beginning of the
   .text section.
3. It is quite aweful so I would love to hear a cleaner solution

**Update**

I've found a solution for 1) problem. Again it is an awefull hack:

```
int main() {
    volatile bool force_false = false;
    if (force_false) unused_global();
}
```

Comment: Some context would help. Wasting room in the PE image is usually not the best way to do it, whatever you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to write a PE-mutator. I want to start simple and so without having to resize the .text section after the program has been compiled as it would require moving the other sections. Mutations require some additional space as in general I will be replacing operations such as `xor eax, eax` with `mov eax, 1; dec eax` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With VS 2019 the following reserves 4K at the beginning and end of the code segment, respectively.

```
#pragma section(".constext", read)
#pragma section(".xonstext", read)
#pragma comment(linker, "/merge:.constext=.text")
#pragma comment(linker, "/merge:.xonstext=.text")

extern "C" __declspec(allocate(".constext")) const char before[0x1000]{ __COUNTER__ };
extern "C" __declspec(allocate(".xonstext")) const char after[0x1000] { __COUNTER__ };

int main()
{
    return before[0] + after[0] - 1;
}
```

The mapfile confirms the placement.

```
Preferred load address is 00400000

Start         Length     Name                   Class
0001:00000000 00001000H .constext               CODE
0001:00001000 00000bc8H .text$mn                CODE
0001:00001bc8 00001000H .xonstext               CODE
0002:00000000 000000b4H .idata$5                DATA
[...]

 Address         Publics by Value              Rva+Base       Lib:Object
[...]
0001:00000000       _before                    00401000     constext.obj
0001:00001000       _main                      00402000 f   constext.obj
[...]
0001:00001bc8       _after                     00402bc8     constext.obj
0002:00000000       __imp__SetUnhandledExceptionFilter@4 00404000     kernel32:KERNEL32.dll
[...]
```

Rather curiously, the optimized compile recognizes the `return` from `main` as a plain `0` but does not cause the dummy arrays references to be optimized away.

```
PUBLIC  _main
;       COMDAT  _main
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_main   PROC    ; COMDAT
; 14   :        return before[0] + after[0] - 1;
        xor     eax, eax
; 15   : }
        ret 0
_main   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
```