# How to correctly extend .text section in CLR compatible PE file

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, portable-executable

I want to correctly extend .text section in PE file according to a File Alignment or Section Alignment.

Details:

Let's start from scratch.
I have .net v4.8 project with several small classes like

```cs
public class A1
{
    public int IntProperty {get;set;}
}
public class A2
{
    public string StringProperty {get;set;}
}
```

It doesn't really matter what these classes are.
After my compilation using MSBuild v16 I have a PE file. (exe or dll dosn't matter either).
Then I expand the .text section with File- or Section alignment(I tried both).
So, if compiled PE file have 512, 1024 or 2048 alignment - that works fine.
But when it have 4096 or 8192 bytes - it doesn't work.
This is the code example, how I do it:

```cpp
    BYTE* dos_header_ptr = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(dosHeader2);
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64* nt_header2 = reinterpret_cast<TNT_HEADERS*>(dos_header_ptr + dosHeader2->e_lfanew);
    const IMAGE_FILE_HEADER* file_header = &nt_header2->FileHeader;
    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64* optional_headers2 = &nt_header2->OptionalHeader;

    DWORD file_alignment = optional_headers2->FileAlignment;

    file_alignment = optional_headers2->SectionAlignment;

    std::vector<IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*> sections = ExtractSections(nt_header2);

    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* section_header_text2 = sections[0];
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* section_header_rsrc2 = sections[1];

    file_info* old_file_info = file_info2;
    file_info2 = RelocateBufferWithDisplacement(old_file_info, file_alignment, section_header_text2);

    // Update pointers and VA
    dosHeader2 = reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*>(file_info2->buffer);
    dos_header_ptr = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(dosHeader2);
    nt_header2 = reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64*>(dos_header_ptr + dosHeader2->e_lfanew);

    file_header = &nt_header2->FileHeader;

    sections.clear();
    sections = ExtractSections<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64>(nt_header2);
    
    section_header_text2 = sections[0];
    section_header_rsrc2 = sections[1];

    section_header_text2->SizeOfRawData += file_alignment;
    section_header_text2->Misc.VirtualSize = section_header_text2->SizeOfRawData;

    for(int i=1; i<sections.size(); i++)
        sections[i]->PointerToRawData += file_alignment;

    optional_headers2 = &nt_header2->OptionalHeader;
    optional_headers2->SizeOfCode += file_alignment;

    delete old_file_info;

    FlushToFile(input_params.file_name_output, file_info2);
```

RelocateBufferWithDisplacement function

```cpp
file_info* RelocateBufferWithDisplacement(file_info* file_info2, DWORD file_alignment, IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* text_section_header)
{
    // COPY BUFFERS
    DWORD new_file_size = file_info2->file_size + file_alignment;
    byte* new_buffer = new byte[new_file_size];

    DWORD first_part_of_file_size = text_section_header->PointerToRawData + text_section_header->SizeOfRawData;
    byte* end_first_part_old = file_info2->buffer + first_part_of_file_size;
    byte* start_free_zone_of_file_ptr_new = new_buffer + first_part_of_file_size;
    byte* second_part_of_file_ptr_new = start_free_zone_of_file_ptr_new + file_alignment;

    std::copy(file_info2->buffer, end_first_part_old, new_buffer);
    std::fill(start_free_zone_of_file_ptr_new, second_part_of_file_ptr_new, 0);
    std::copy(end_first_part_old, file_info2->buffer + file_info2->file_size, second_part_of_file_ptr_new);

    return new file_info(new_file_size, new_buffer);
}
```

ExtractSections method

```cpp
std::vector<IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*>& ExtractSections(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64* nt_headers)
{
    std::vector<IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*>* result = new std::vector<IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*>();
    for(int i=0; i < nt_headers->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
        result->push_back(reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*>(reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(nt_headers) + sizeof(TNT_HEADERS) + i * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)));

    return *result;
}
```

That works the same way of both x32/x64 files, but now only x64 version is considered to simplification.
I also noticed:
If I use a larger project (e.g. up to 30000 code lines) I can't do it even for 2048 file alignment. Only for 512 and 1024. But if the project is almost clear - only 8192 fails.
I expect that something should be also updated, but I don't know what exactly.

Just a high level vision of the code:
[image]

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the specific problem you are trying to solve using this procedure?

Comment: This is extremely hard for us to debug just by looking at your code. My suggestion to you would be to try and create the file that you're now trying to produce with your patch logic, but with the normal tool chain - or as close to it as you can get. That way you can compare PE dumps of yours and that one to see how they differ.

Comment: @IInspectable I need extend .text section to store some extra info by specific address. But any way it not so important, because I just want to know what is the problem on this step.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thanks for advice. So I can create compile it as tool but actually I'm not sure that it can help us. I already investigated a lot of time a difference between in- and output files in terms of bytes dump. but anyway, probably, I will add it...

Comment: @YVEF See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62012531/5538420) for example how to reserve additional room in the code segment. Then compare the PE made that way with the one you are generating.